# Import categories in magento through script

Tags: php, magento, categories

Hello I have just started to learn magento. Now I was trying to import category in magento through script.

my magento code looks like

```
<?php
    require_once 'businessclasses.php';
    define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
    require_once MAGENTO . '/app/Mage.php';
    umask(0);
    $count = 0;

    echo "<pre>";
    $data= new getCSV();
    $rows=$data->getRootCategories(); // Gets the list of root categories.

    foreach($rows as $row) {
        echo $categoryName = $row['d']; // Name of Category

        // Create category object
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        $category->setStoreId(1); // 'US-Store' store is assigned to this category

        $rootCategory['name'] = $categoryName;
        $rootCategory['path'] = "23/25"; // this is the catgeory path
        $rootCategory['display_mode'] = "PRODUCTS";
        $rootCategory['is_active'] = 1;
        $category->addData($rootCategory);

        try {
            $category->save();
            echo $rootCategoryId = $category->getId();
        }
        catch (Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>
```

This code runs without an error and also this line

```
echo $rootCategoryId = $category->getId();
```

prints unique IDs for each category (loop) but when i see at the admin pannel it shows me nothing. Like no category imported.

I have reffered this  [Question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379972/how-to-add-a-category-to-magento-via-setup-script)  but it is not helping.

any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey guys I got an answer.

```
$rootCategory['path'] = "1/23/25"; // this is the catgeory path  <-- I was giving this path wrong.
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you've got your answer yourself. However, if anyone looking for some other tools for category and product and other import/export, I recommend Magmi http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/, awesome tool saved me a lot of time .